# Can anyone help me debug this?

Tags: c++

I'm fairy new at c++ and trying to make a simple program that returns the address of a char, here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char returnaddress(char* x){
char *t = &x;
return *t;
}
int main()
{
  char y = "a";
  returnaddress(&y);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x` is already a pointer, so you should not be taking its address here `char *t = &x;`. Just use it as is `char *t = x;`

Comment: also `char y = 'a';` **not** `"a"`.

Comment: If `returnaddress` is supposed to return the address of something why is it returning `char` and not a pointer type? Also, why a function in the first place? You already have `&` to give you the address of something.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to create a function to return the address of a variable.  That feature is already in the language.

```
int main()
{
  char y = 'a'; // single quotes for single characters.
  char * pointer_to_y = &y; // This replaces your function.
  std::cout << "Address is: " << static_cast<void *>(pointer_to_y) << "\n";
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The `static_cast` is required to force output of the address instead of calling the overload for printing C-Style strings.

Answer (score 0):

the address of your char is `&y`. no need for the wrong function. the type of `&x` in your function is `char**` so the code cannot compile. also chars in c++ are delimited by ticks not quotes